# Is there a math field that studies something like this?

Tags: reference-request, rational-numbers

I was having a blurry thinking of differences about rational and irrational numbers, then I had the idea of ploting them in a specific way:

$$\frac{1}{2}=0.5$$

Getting that value, I've thought about a function for the digit positions, which in the given case would give me

$$\begin{matrix}
{f(1)}&=&{0}\\
{f(2)}&=&{5}
\end{matrix}
$$

And in the case of

$$\frac{1}{3}=0.33333...$$

Would give me

$$\begin{matrix}
{f(1)}&=&{0}\\
{f(2)}&=&{3}\\
{f(3)}&=&{3}\\
{f(4)}&=&{3}\\
{f(5)}&=&{3}\\
{f(n>5)}&=&{3}\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I've even plotted some examples:

[image]

Is there a math field that studies something like that? The nearest thing that comes to my mind are the Ford Circles (although I know they're very different). In the [Ford circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle), there is a relation between the radius of the circle and the number it represents. I was thinking also if such a relation could be found in this?

I'm not thinking about a relation exactly like Ford circles, I'm thinking about a deeper relation between the line and the given number.

Comment: I may not discover something useful but I guess I'll do mathematics research someday, this is a small pathetic step that I can do with the little I know.

Comment: @Prism Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Some fields that occur to me are:

1. Number theory
2. Normal numbers
3. Summations for $\pi$ and other constants
4. Digit-extraction algorithms (for our good friend $\pi$ and other constants
5. Periods of the reciprocals of primes (and other integers) in different bases

Answer (score 1):

Linear algebra:
Represent the numbers as polynomials (assuming x is 0.1, or some positive integer exponent of I guess) in a polynomial vector space.  Let its domain be the natural numbers.  Let f(n) be the inner product of said polynomial with the $n^{th}$ monomial basis vector.

You can probably do some funky stuff with this through the lens some part of more general abstract algebra or algebraic number theory.